# Javascript console.log is not printed on vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJrLS.png)

I just started to learn JS and was trying to printout "Hello,World" the basic.

However,

[Running] and [Done] messages were printed properly but not for the text "Hello,World".

According to other "hello,world" sources from tutorials and documents, "console" was colored with different color except white. Is this point related to this printout problem?

Comment: Try manually execute the code in the terminal

Comment: can i know, how you run your program ?. Simple terminal commands or any other way ?

Comment: @MaverickFabroa It works properly on Terminal. Thank you for leaving me a comment :)

Comment: @AbishekramR I used codeRunner extension to run this code. It works on terminal commands but nothing is printed on OUTPUT tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can debug with external terminal by configuring launch.json (you need to place your file inside a folder to do configuration).

Go to Debug -> Open Configurations

Add `"console": "externalTerminal"` to your launch.json:

```json
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "type": "node",
        "request": "launch",
        "name": "Launch Program",
        "program": "${workspaceFolder}/t.js",
        "console": "externalTerminal"
    }
]
```

Try Debugging and VSCode will debug your output on a separate terminal.

Comment: Your answer fixed my problem! Thank you for leaving me an answer.

Comment: I'm in VS Code right now, and there's no Debug menu.

Comment: @Oscar ensure you have a default build config (Run > Add Configuration...) and then it will open automatically. If you already have a build config open it through Run > Open Configurations.

Answer (score 1):

you need to switch your terminal tab to see the console , its the last one normally

Comment: Thank you for leaving the answer. It works properly when I do my work in terminal tab :)

Answer (score -1):

Open terminal and type node filename.js and run it

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).